# Getting JQuery to load element on page load

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I need my modal pop-up window to show up once the page has loaded, at the moment it is not showing up (only if I click the 'view' link). Can someone tell me how this can be done?

here is my JQuery :

```
$(function() {
     $('#dialog').jqm();
});
```

The link that actions this is:

```
 <a href="#" class="jqModal">view</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jqueryUI dialog.

Then from there you can only do the following:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

Comment: How can I add an overlay to the back of this?

Comment: Use jqueryUI dialog. To add overlay just add the following property.    modal: true

Answer (score 0):

Try [jqueryUI dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="jquery/jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog" class="jqModal" title="This is my title">
        I'm in a dialog!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/bdsCt/) contains an example with an overlay

Comment: Do you know how I could add an overlay to the page with using this modal dialog?

Comment: You could follow this tutorial http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html